# Python3: byte array decoding from urlopen

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, urlopen, utf8-decode

I'm trying to use python to find some words across webpages (just to practice) but I keep running into a problem. This is it:

```
url = 'someWikipage'
hdrs = { 'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11" } 
req = request.Request(url,None,hdrs)
response = urlopen(req)
htmlBytes = response.read()
htmlBytes.decode('utf-8')
```

It brakes on the last line giving me an error (a common one);

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2010' in position 18573: character maps to <undefined>
```

Any ideas about how to prevent or ignore this?

Comment: Are you certain that you're reading a `bytes`?

Comment: Why do you need to `decode`? Seems that htmlBytes is already unicode.

Comment: @PauloBu unicode doesn't have a decode method

Comment: A small part of the output of `htmlBytes` is `b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="client-nojs">\n<head>\n<meta charset="UTF-8" />'` which lets me assume it is indeed a byte array. Also the documentation confirms this.